# How can i dispatch the redux/toolkit action in the react router dom action?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Here is my router

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: "/",
    element: <MainLayout />,
    errorElement: <Error />,
    children: [
      {
        path: "/inventory",
        element: <Inventory />,
      },
      {
        path: "/inventory/:inventoryId",
        element: <InventoryItem />,
        action: inventoryAction
      },
    ],
  }
]);
```

Inside the `inventoryItem`. I got the `inventoryAction` exported. Since this action is not inside the component I can't call the `useCreateNewItemMutation` hook.

```
export const inventoryAction = async ({ request }: any) => {
  const data = await request.formData();
  let dataToSubmit = {
    unitName: data.get("unitName"),
    itemType: data.get("itemType"),
    price: data.get("price"),
    unitCount: data.get("unitCount"),
    inventoryId: data.get("inventoryId"),
  };
  // store.dispatch(useCreateNewItemMutation(dataToSubmit)) // HOW CAN I DISPATCH
  return null;
};

const InventoryItem = ({ params }: any) => {
  const { inventoryId } = useParams();

  const [addItemModalActive, setAddItemModalActive] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Form
        method="post"
        action={`/inventory/${inventoryId}`}
        className="flex flex-col w-1/2"
      >
        <label className="text-sm text-gray-500 mb-2" htmlFor="item name">
          Item name
        </label>
        <input
          placeholder="Enter Item Name"
          id="item name"
          name="unitName"
          className="border rounded w-full mb-4 p-2 text-sm"
        ></input>

        <label className="text-sm text-gray-500 mb-2" htmlFor="item type">
          Item type
        </label>
        <input
          placeholder="Eg food,drink..."
          id="item type"
          name="itemType"
          className="border rounded w-full mb-4 p-2 text-sm"
        ></input>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

As you can see in the `inventoryAction` function I want to call `useCreateNewItemMutation` hook.

How can I accomplish this?

store.ts

```js
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    [apiSlice.reducerPath]: apiSlice.reducer,
    auth: authSliceReducer,
    organization: organizationSliceReducer,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(apiSlice.middleware),
  devTools: true,
});

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  baseQuery,
  tagTypes: ["User", "Inventory", "Item"],
  endpoints: (builder) => ({}),
});
```

Here is the file which exporting the mutation function

```js
export const itemApiSlice = apiSlice.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    createNewItem: builder.mutation({
      query: (data) => ({
        url: `http://localhost:3000/item`,
        method: "POST",
        body: data,
      }),
      
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useCreateNewItemMutation } = itemApiSlice;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call React hooks outside React components and custom React hooks. In the loader you can manually dispatch actions directly to the store. The key here is that you can't use the generated React hooks from your endpoints, but you can manually [initiate](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/endpoints#initiate) one.

Example:

```js
import { store } from '../path/to/store';
import { itemApiSlice } from '../path/to/itemApiSlice';

export const inventoryAction = async ({ request }: any) => {
  const data = await request.formData();

  const dataToSubmit = {
    unitName: data.get("unitName"),
    itemType: data.get("itemType"),
    price: data.get("price"),
    unitCount: data.get("unitCount"),
    inventoryId: data.get("inventoryId"),
  };

  store.dispatch(
    itemApiSlice.endpoints.createNewItem.initiate(dataToSubmit)
  );

  return null;
};
```